# What is this cloud of red pond creatures?

Tags: species-identification

Today I came across a pond in the Netherlands where I noticed a cloud, for lack of a better word, of small red creatures swirling around near the surface of the water, as can be seen in this video:

https://youtu.be/ZQMox-bbJ9s

And here is a picture:

[image]

The surface was unfortunately quite reflective, but the motion is visible. The creatures were too small for me to see any structure to them with the naked eye. Some tadpoles can be seen in the video, which are much larger. They would swim straight through the cloud now and then, so perhaps the tadpoles consider the red stuff food. The entire cloud consisted of various dense clusters connected with less dense or thinner parts, as can be seen to some extent in the video, and its total size was perhaps 2 meters or so.

What was I looking at?

Comment: Can you kindly add some pics/screen-shots here too as: 1-) Not everyone can check a video link 2-) External links are prone to modifications or even deleting. Thanks!

Comment: Where were these pictures taken? Also,the video is too short.Try to get a longer one next time.

Comment: You don't say where this was, but my first suspicion would be some sort of algae bloom.

Comment: @JeffreyBarber it was in the Netherlands, I added it to the question. Are algae generally mobile?